# Entity Framework - Mapping decimal(13,0) problem

Tags: entity-framework, mapping

I'm migrating the aplication of my company (that nowadays run over SQL Server and Oracle) to ASP NET MVC and Entity Framework for persistence.

A create my Entity Model based on SQL Server Database e separately I create a SSDL for Oracle (for Oracle I use DevArt dotConnect for Oracle Provider) and I get some pain troubles.

My table primary keys are on SQL Server are of type decimal(13,0) and on Oracle are number(13,0) but Oracle map it's type to Int64 and SQL Server to decimal, but I need that SQL Server map it to Int64.

I make these modification manually on Entity Data Model and for create records it's works fine, but when I have to delete or update some record I got these error:

The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Decimal'
Parameter name: value

> at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbConstantExpression..ctor(DbCommandTree commandTree, Object value, TypeUsage constantType)
>      at  System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.GenerateValueExpression(DbCommandTree commandTree, EdmProperty property, PropagatorResult value)
>      at  System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.GenerateEqualityExpression(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree, EdmProperty property, PropagatorResult value)
>      at  System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.BuildPredicate(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree, PropagatorResult referenceRow, PropagatorResult current, TableChangeProcessor processor, Boolean& rowMustBeTouched)
>      at  System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.BuildDeleteCommand(PropagatorResult oldRow, TableChangeProcessor processor)
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.TableChangeProcessor.CompileCommands(ChangeNode changeNode, UpdateCompiler compiler)

Someone can help me?

Why Entity Framework mapping are so fixed? It could be more flexible?

Ps.: The error that I got, I suspect that is because of a association.

I have a Entity named Province and another named Country and I think that the association between these Entities are causing the problem at update and delete.

Regards,

Douglas Aguiar

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not help you, but i had the same error from doing this same thing. So I edited the Conceptual model and change the primary key field from Int32 to Decimal. So far, seems to have fixed things. I still need to test again against Sql Server and make sure this didnt break it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error "The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Decimal' Parameter name: value" as you posted in your question.  I had changed the default data types from Decimal to Int32 as this better reflects the true typing.  When I first hit this error I rolled back the type changes and was still getting an exception but it changed just slightly but led to further digging.  Bottom line, in my scenario we were expecting a trigger to populate the PK during persistence via Before Insert directive.  The problem was that the domain class built by EF was setting the PK at 0 so the trigger was never firing as the incoming PK was not null.  Of course EF will not let you set the Entity PK to be nullable.  Maybe this will help someone else in the future.